# Fused Location Provider Client always returns first location as null

Tags: android, android-location

I have an activity with a button, and on click of said button the location should be displayed. But the first click always returns null, the second click returns the correct information. I tried using a delay but that only delays the alert dialog creation, still the first value on first button click is null.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    private Double longitude, latitude;
    private Float accuracy;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        Button testButton = findViewById(R.id.test_button);
        testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getCurrentLocation();
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Current Location")
                        .setMessage("Location: " + latitude +", "+ longitude +
                                "\nAccuracy: " + String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%.2f", accuracy) +"m")
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                        .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        // Get last known location, and check for null.
                        if(location!=null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make variable protected, so do this :

```
 protected FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
 protected Double longitude, latitude;
 protected Float accuracy;
```

Instead of that :

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
private Double longitude, latitude;
private Float accuracy;
```

Comment: No, nothing has changed. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Build the AlertDialog after the Location is available, like this:

```
private void getCurrentLocation() {
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Get last known location, and check for null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                                .setTitle("Current Location")
                                .setMessage("Location: " + latitude + ", " + longitude +
                                        "\nAccuracy: " + String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.2f", accuracy) + "m")
                                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                                .show();

                    }
                }
            });
}
```